Creating boundaries for moving an image inside a squared view
I am building a crop component in React Native. I've already assembled some code (https://snack.expo.dev/@leurs247/cropper).
Explanation:
It's goal is to crop the given image into a square, but the user can choose which part of the image to crop (and it's also possible to scale the image). At the start, the scale is 1, so the image has it's original size. The background of the square is pink, en when moving the images, the image should be bounded inside the square so no pink background is visible. This works. But when scaling > 1 (up to scale=3), the boundaries are not calculated correctly. When moving the image, it's possible to move outside of the boundaries so the pink background becomes visible.
This is the complete code for the cropper component:
import React, {useMemo} from 'react';
import {View, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';
import {GestureDetector, Gesture} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {useSharedValue, clamp} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';

const Cropper = props => {
  const {width} = useWindowDimensions();

  const {ratio, scaledWidth, scaledHeight} = useMemo(() => {
    let ratio;
    let scaledWidth;
    let scaledHeight;

    if (props.width < props.height) {
      ratio = width / props.width;
      scaledWidth = width;
      scaledHeight = props.height * ratio;
    } else if (props.height < props.width) {
      ratio = width / props.height;
      scaledWidth = props.width * ratio;
      scaledHeight = width;
    } else {
      ratio = width / props.width;
      scaledWidth = width;
      scaledHeight = width;
    }

    return {ratio, scaledWidth, scaledHeight};
  }, [props.width, props.height, width]);

  const posX = useSharedValue(0);
  const posY = useSharedValue(0);
  const transX = useSharedValue(0);
  const transY = useSharedValue(0);
  const scaleT = useSharedValue(1);
  const maxLeft = useSharedValue(0);
  const maxRight = useSharedValue(0);
  const maxTop = useSharedValue(0);
  const maxBottom = useSharedValue(0);
  const x = useSharedValue(0);
  const y = useSharedValue(0);

  const pan = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart(e => {})
    .onUpdate(e => {
      const totalWidth = scaledWidth * scaleT.value;
      const totalHeight = Math.round(scaledHeight * scaleT.value);

      maxLeft.value = -(totalWidth - width) * scaleT.value;
      maxRight.value = (totalWidth - width) * (scaleT.value - 1);
      maxTop.value = -((totalHeight - width) * scaleT.value);
      maxBottom.value = (totalHeight - width) * (scaleT.value - 1);

      posX.value = clamp(
        transX.value + e.translationX,
        maxLeft.value,
        maxRight.value,
      );

      posY.value = clamp(
        transY.value + e.translationY,
        maxTop.value,
        maxBottom.value,
      );
    })
    .onEnd(e => {
      transX.value = posX.value;
      transY.value = posY.value;
    });

  const composed = Gesture.Race(pan);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{width, height: width, overflow: 'hidden'}}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={composed}>
          <Animated.Image
            source={{uri: props.uri}}
            style={{
              transform: [
                {
                  translateX: posX,
                },
                {
                  translateY: posY,
                },
                {
                  scale: scaleT,
                },
              ],
              width: scaledWidth,
              height: scaledHeight,
            }}
          />
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
      <Slider
        minimumValue={1}
        maximumValue={3}
        value={1}
        onValueChange={value => {
          scaleT.value = value;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Cropper;

I think the main part for this to work correctly is with the maxLeft, maxRight, maxTop and maxBottom animated values.
Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Based on my quick analysis, your calculations for maxLeft, maxRight, maxTop, and maxBottom are not correctly limiting the image's position when scaled.
So you need to adjust the calculations to correctly reflect the boundaries of the image within the crop area when scaling is applied.
Try this out:
const pan = Gesture.Pan()
  .onUpdate(e => {
    const displayedWidth = scaledWidth * scaleT.value;
    const displayedHeight = scaledHeight * scaleT.value;

    maxLeft.value = width - displayedWidth;
    maxRight.value = 0;
    maxTop.value = width - displayedHeight;
    maxBottom.value = 0;

    posX.value = clamp(
      transX.value + e.translationX,
      maxLeft.value,
      maxRight.value,
    );

    posY.value = clamp(
      transY.value + e.translationY,
      maxTop.value,
      maxBottom.value,
    );
  })
  .onEnd(e => {
    transX.value = posX.value;
    transY.value = posY.value;
  });


In the code above I adjusted so when the image is zoomed in, displayedWidth becomes larger than width.
Then maxLeft.value becomes a negative number, representing the maximum leftward movement before the right edge of the image would no longer cover the crop area.
The clamping posX.value between maxLeft.value (most negative) and 0 (no movement to the right beyond the crop area's left edge) ensures the image stays within bounds.
The same logic applies to vertical movement, using displayedHeight and maxTop.value. It's a bit tricky but you can test yourself and let me know if this works properly.
One thing I cannot test is that transX.value and transY.value are set appropriately. So that's up to you xD

Hi, sorry for my belated answer. I already "fixed" the problem by setting the transform origin to x=0, y=0. This way, the calculations in my code are correct. It's not the ideal situation for me (because when you rescale the image it moves back to 0,0) but it works for now.
